# How to mount a software RAID0 array in CentOS without formatting

Tags: centos, mount, raid-0

Recently my software RAID0 array had a SMART error and so I had to get 2 new drives to create another RAID0 to re-install CentOS 6.

The 2 previous drives were saved; and re-inserted. But I don't know how to re-mount it so that I can grab the data within the drives.

I see the drives within 'fdisk -l', and have determined the following drives to be the old drives. (sda and sdd, are the new ones; but not pasted here)

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005159c

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1       60802   488385536   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006dd55

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          26      204800   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2              26        4106    32768000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3            4106        5380    10240000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb4            5380       60802   445172736    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5            5380       60802   445171712   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Can anyone guide me on this? It would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Remember to mount read-only, just in case!

Answer (score 1):

I've not used raid0 before, but assuming this was created using mdadm (ie software raid), you can probably do something like

```
mdadm --assemble mdX  /dev/disk1 /dev/disk2
```

This will make the raid available and you can then mount it/recover from the disk.

```
mount /dev/mdX /mnt
```

(Obviously replace mdX  and disk1 and disk2 with appropriate resource names)

Answer (score 0):

You can mount individually the drive with (assuming ext4 file system):

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

and recover data from the old drive into the new ones.

Comment: I think this would work for RAID1, but I can't see how it would work with RAID0, which stripes the information across 2 disks, without redundancy.

Comment: You are right Nobblier, you have reassemble the raid as davidgo sugguests