# Change raid partition to ext4

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, arch-linux, ext4

I have an external HHD that has somehow been formatted as 'linux-raid' when I look at it in gParted. I have no idea how I have accidentally done this but I guess I misused some new feature of an [open source tool](https://freefilesync.org) I use.

$fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: 106X            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 395E65FF-3A23-4DDF-9684-2E2D3DDBC43C

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.7T Linux filesystem
```

$file -skr /dev/sdc1

```
/dev/sdc1:  Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=c2bc2f29-c0ee-48e1-93c3-7ef1ad743190 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

I have looked at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/971549/how-to-convert-a-software-raid-1-partition-to-non-raid-partition#971570) but I want to confirm before trying this as I did not use `mdadm` directly. I don't know how to even confirm what type of RAID is being used. If RAID 1 perhaps I can use [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/588961/364893) but I know I do not have enough local storage to copy the files across.

I am using arch.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo file -skr /dev/sdc1`?)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski updated the question

Comment: Apologies, the command failed the first time I tried it whilst leaving off the partition number worked. I have edited the question with the correct command output.